# How to modify the the_post_thumbnail function on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, srcset

First of all: is it even possible?

I'd like to get a function that returns an srcset `<img>` tag to make my wordpress layout responsive. This is important for me because my wrapper is 1400 wide, which is good for screens wider than 1400 @1 or 700 @2, but for mobile phones is too wide, and 720px width would be enough for @2 and even @3 screens (as they could get sharper but eye wouldn't notice too much).

The problem is I can't know which thumbnail size to serve while processing the php... so I'd like to use a `srcset`. To do that I know I must write something on the `functions.php`. But what should I do and how? Should I modify `the_post_thumbnail()` function? Or should I create a new one? In that case, how can I get the different image names from the different sizes of the post thumbnail?

Comment: I think you can add a `post_thumbnail_html` filter and return pretty much anything you like to replace what `the_post_thumbnail` outputs. Might give you a clean way of doing it, or at least something to search for examples... (That filter gets passed the attachment ID, and then you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to get various different sizes of the image `src` to use in your `srcset`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wp [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) and [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) functions to create yourself the `<img>` tag:

```
global $post;
$url1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
$url2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium');
<img src="<?php echo $url1[0]; ?>" srcset="<?php echo $url2[0]; ?> 500w" alt="alt-text" />
```

Where "thumbnail" and "medium" are the image sizes name. For example, the default WordPress sizes are thumbnail, medium, large and full. Your theme can have more sizes declared.

If you are inside the loop you don't need to declare de `global $post`.

Comment: what should $size contain? 720, 720w, 720px, 720x480... ?

Comment: Sorry I give you the wrong code, I have edited my answer and include also explanation about the size parameter.

Comment: can I reunite this code in a single function from the functions.php file?

Comment: yes, of course, you can create a function on functions.php file with the code and call it where necessary

Comment: I'll check it when I get home

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to modify the_post_thumbnail function.

use the below filter to modify the output generated by the_post_thumbnail  function.

```
           add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'your_function', 10, 6 );
```